# code reuse with an inline query inside a SP

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, code-reuse

This below is abstraction. Queries are much more complex. Principle exactly the same.

I have a Stored Procedure that does:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE T1.fk IN (SELECT id FROM T2);
```

In reality this inline query is very complex and is being used in many other stored procedures. I wish to maintain it's code in only one place. 
Right now, the worst case scenario, is this inner query returns about 22K records.

How do I put this inner query in only one place (as a function, something like include,macro etc...)

Efficiency is not important in this case. Maintainability less code, is.

Answer (score 4):

a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)?

```
CREATE VIEW MyQuery AS
 SELECT * FROM T1
 WHERE T1.fk IN (SELECT id FROM T2);
```

Comment: I need to reuse ONLY the inner query

Comment: put the inner query in a view, don't see much gain anyway if it's that simple

Comment: it is not simple, I just made it simple for the sake of a clearer question. Ill see how it goes with View

Comment: @ItayMoav - you may need to make it less simple, if a View doesn't work for you. Perhaps a function inserting into a temp table would be a better approach, but it's difficult to tell with the current question.